# GDI+ error upon upload multiple images then create thumbnails

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing

I've got an image upload page that works just fine when I only upload the files.

I added a 'Create Thumbnail' function. It looks like the file system has a handle on the images when the thumbnail process starts.

I get the 'unspecified GDI+ error' only when the image is over about 250K.  When the files are below 250K, thumbnails are created as expected.

What are my options?  Is there an elegant solution here?  I want something not hacky.
Also, I am using HttpFileCollection so we can upload multiple images at one time. I've tried to use .Dispose on the Thumbnail creation, but it fails before we get to this point.

```
public void Upload_Click(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
 string directory = Server.MapPath(@"~\images\");
  HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
  for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
  {
    HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];

    if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
    {
      string fileName = hpf.FileName;
      fileName = fileName.Replace(" ", "");
      hpf.SaveAs(fileName);
      createThumbnail(fileName);
    }
  }
}

private void createThumbnail(string filename)
{
  Image image = Image.FromFile(filename);
  Image thumb = image.GetThumbnailImage(100,100, () => false, IntPtr.Zero);
  thumb.Save(filename);
  image.Dispose();
  thumb.Dispose();
 }
```

Comment: Can we see the offending code?

Comment: try to remove the image.dispose(); and  thumb.dispose();

Comment: There is [absolutely no elegant solution to image resizing on the server](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/), unless you [use a library designed for exactly that](http://imageresizing.net). GetThumbnailImage is really poor quality, on top of all the memory management nightmares you'll encounter. Also, you'll need to specify encoding parameters, the default quality is unsuitably large for thumbnails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please let me know if this works any better:

```
    public string ImageDirectory { get { return Server.MapPath(@"~\images\"); } }

    public void OnUploadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var files = HttpContext.Request.Files.AllKeys.AsEnumerable()
            .Select(k =>HttpContext.Request.Files[k]);

        foreach(var file in files)
        {
            if(file.ContentLength <= 0)
                continue;

            string savePath = GetFullSavePath(file);
            var dimensions = new Size(100, 100);

            CreateThumbnail(file,savePath,dimensions);
        }
    }

    private void CreateThumbnail(HttpPostedFile file,string savePath, Size dimensions)
    {
        using (var image = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream))
        {
            using (var thumb = image.GetThumbnailImage(dimensions.Width, dimensions.Height, () => false, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                thumb.Save(savePath);
            }
        }
    }

    private string GetFullSavePath(HttpPostedFile file)
    {
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName).Replace(" ", "");
        string savePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(this.ImageDirectory, fileName);
        return savePath;
    }
```

Edit -

The foreach should have followed more to this pattern:

```
var files = HttpContext.Request.Files.AllKeys.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(k =>HttpContext.Request.Files[k]);

foreach(var file in files)
{

}
```

Comment: This fixed the problem.  There's a few issues with this code; mainly a casting issue between string and Request.Files (from the 'foreach (HttpPostedFile....)' line.
And I needed to save the uploaded file, too.  But after hacking around, I have it saving both the original file and the thumbnail.  It's not pretty yet, but the original issue is solved.  Thanks for providing a clear & straight-forward answer.

Comment: @JonHiggens Sorry about the cast error. I didn't actually try to compile or run this, other then ensuring it was syntactically correct.

Comment: no problem - I assume we can't do something like this:

    (HttpPostedFile file in (HttpPostedFile)HttpContext.Request.Files)

Comment: @JonHiggens Yeah it looks like I was parsing the file collection incorrectly. See my edit for the proper way to use `foreach` against the file collection.

Comment: @JonHiggens Fyi - Again, I didn't actually run it, other then typing it up in linqPad and seeing it if ran compiled. Looks like it should work though. I'm a little curious why this solution worked where your original code failed. At first glance it should have worked. All I did was clean it up as if I was doing a code review for you.

Comment: It didn't work this time either.  I get the following error: 
 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and the best extension method overload 'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable(System.Data.DataTable)' has some invalid arguments

It's okay though, I can tinker around with it.  Thanks.

Comment: @JonHiggens `using System.Linq;` at the top ?

Comment: perfect.  Everything now works as it should.  I should have realized by your using linqPad that it'd use System.Linq.  I'm not sure why it was working where my original failed.    I thought the file was locked for some reason.  Perhaps the 'using' statement doesn't have the same issue as my original problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to create your thumbnails.

```
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
       Bitmap originalBMP = new Bitmap(ms);

       int maxWidth = 200;
       int maxHeight = 200;

       // Calculate the new image dimensions 
       int origWidth = originalBMP.Width;
       int origHeight = originalBMP.Height;
       double sngRatio = Convert.ToDouble(origWidth) / Convert.ToDouble(origHeight);

       // New dimensions
       int newWidth = 0;
       int newHeight = 0;
       try
       {
           // max 200 by 200

           if ((origWidth <= maxWidth && origHeight <= maxHeight) || origWidth <= maxWidth)
           {
               newWidth = origWidth;
               newHeight = origHeight;
           }
           else
           {
               // Width longer (shrink width)
               newWidth = 200;
               newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(newWidth) / sngRatio);
           }

           // Create a new bitmap which will hold the previous resized bitmap 
           Bitmap newBMP = new Bitmap(originalBMP, newWidth, newHeight);
           // Create a graphic based on the new bitmap 
           Graphics oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBMP);

           // Set the properties for the new graphic file 
           oGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
           oGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
           // Draw the new graphic based on the resized bitmap 
           oGraphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;

           oGraphics.DrawImage(originalBMP, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

           // Save the new graphic file to the server 
           EncoderParameters p = new EncoderParameters(1);
           p.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, 70);     // Percent Compression

           MemoryStream savedBmp = new MemoryStream();

           newBMP.Save(savedBmp, ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()[1], p);

                          // Once finished with the bitmap objects, we deallocate them. 
           originalBMP.Dispose();
           newBMP.Dispose();
           oGraphics.Dispose();
           savedBmp.Dispose();
```

Certainly a bit more work but it does give you greater control.

Comment: With the two Adam's answering, I'm sure we'll figure it out.

Comment: You should be wrapping the non-managed resources in `using` clauses to insure you are not leaking them in the event of an exception.